# Google+ SignIn API and emails

Tags: c#, google-plus, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to use the Google+ Sign-in API in ASP.NET using this code:

```
var flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
{
   ClientSecrets = secrets,
   Scopes = new string[] { PlusService.Scope.PlusLogin }
});

token = flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync("me", code, "postmessage", CancellationToken.None).Result;

var service = new Oauth2Service(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer());
var request = service.Tokeninfo();
request.AccessToken = token.AccessToken;
var info = request.Execute();
// info.Email is null here
```

As stated the `Email` field at `info` is null. If I add anything else to the `Scopes` like "email" or "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read" ([reference](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#email)) I get "invalid_scope"

Leaving it to people:get API ([reference](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get)) to get the emails is not any better:

```
var credential = new UserCredential(flow, info.UserId, token);
 plusService = new PlusService(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer()
 {
     ApplicationName = "Test",
     HttpClientInitializer = credential
 });

 var me = plusService.People.Get("me").Execute();
 // me.Emails is null
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Scopes array you'll need to add `PlusService.Scope.UserinfoEmail` in order to be able to view the email-related information.

```
Scopes = new string[] { PlusService.Scope.PlusLogin,  PlusService.Scope.UserinfoEmail }
```

Also, you will need to declare the additional scope in the "data-scope" attribute of your sign in button. In this case, it would be

```
data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT.: If you're using https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-csharp/ as your starting point, your data should look like this:
http://pastebin.com/VJzhzyyk

Comment: no this doesn't work, if I add like you suggest IO get  Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: Error:"invalid_scope", Description:"", Uri:""

Comment: @Toolkit please check if those two are the only scopes you've requested in both the C# part and the html

Comment: @ EvilBeer yes the only two scopes. The moment I add a second scope to c# I have invalid_scope error. I can't find any working c# example with PlusService.Scope.UserinfoEmail

Comment: @Toolkit could you share your implementation of it? (The answer I have posted is what I'm using in my application successfully, so the issue is most likely somewhere else)

Comment: I based on official example https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-csharp/ It has few bugs but I can see userId. If I expand it with PlusService.Scope.UserinfoEmail  and change data-scope as you suggest I get invalid_scope message. Can you modify it to get email and publish here? This would be awesome. But I can tell you that the author himself told me to switch to javascript client, see comments here http://gusclass.com/blog/2014/07/29/using-google-apis-from-console-apps-in-net/

Comment: @Toolkit Just tried the example you've provided in the link - worked like a charm! Please post your g-signin and scope setup in a pastebin somewhere and share the link with me :)

Comment: Here's what it should look like: http://pastebin.com/VJzhzyyk (Don't forget to add the client id/secret in the handler as well)

Comment: I'll look into updating the sample to include an option to switch to email. It looks like you were updating the server-side but not the client-side auth scopes.

Comment: OK, i found the problem, I had duplicate data-scope in the button. I can get email OK now except that I can't disconnect the account, it says "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.". And periodically I have some errors about https frame being loaded via http